# $_POST to CSV in php

Tags: php, csv

I've a php file to export php data to csv.

But I've got the following  error

> **Warning**:  mysql_num_fields() expects parameter 1 to be resource  boolean given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\exporttocsv3\export2csv.php** on line **28**

and

> **Warning**:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be
>   resource  boolean given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\exporttocsv3\export2csv.php** on line **40**

**Form.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="export2csv.php">
    <input type = "text" name ="wow" placeholder="Search by name">
<button  name="submit" type="submit">Wew</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**export2csv.php**

```
<?php

// Database Connection

$host="localhost";
$uname="root";
$pass="louchin";
$database = "phppot_examples";  

$connection=mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pass); 

echo mysql_error();

//or die("Database Connection Failed");
$selectdb=mysql_select_db($database) or die("Database could not be selected");  
$result=mysql_select_db($database)
or die("database cannot be selected <br>");



if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$name = $_POST['wow'];

$output = "";
$table = "toy"; 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, code FROM $table WHERE (name LIKE '%$name%'");
$columns_total  = mysql_num_fields($sql);

// Get The Field Name

for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
    $heading    =   mysql_field_name($sql, $i);
    $output     .= '"'.$heading.'",';
}
$output .="\n";

// Get Records from the table

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
}
$output .="\n";
}

// Download the file

$filename =  "myFile.csv";
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

echo $output;
exit;
}   
?>
```

As you can see it's in mysql but I'll convert it later to mysqli query. Thank you for future answers

Comment: missing ) in query

Comment: you miss ')' in your sql query.

Comment: yes thank you ! I've read it on the answer though! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got lacking close parenthesis in your query. That's why it shows an error.

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, code FROM $table WHERE (name LIKE '%$name%')")
```